# Upload to firestore works on debug, but not on release

Tags: flutter, upload, firebase-storage

I need to upload an image file to firestore

```
Future<void> _uploadImage() async {
FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref('$id/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}_1.png')
    .putData(_imageFile!);
```

}

The image is saved as bytes. The problem is it works on testing in chrome. But not if I export.

Comment: What line of the code you shared throws that error? Also note that we can't see how `_imageFile` is initialied, so if that's relevant to the problem, you'll want to show it too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple.

Dont use canvaskit to build. use html